# Building battle ship in processing. How do i connect the ships together and randomize the location of the ships?

Tags: java, processing

ive been working on this side project trying to make a battle ship game from some time now. I have come across a few things I do not know how to do. I was wondering if anyone knew how I could make each of the five ships with their appropriate lengths and then randomize their location on the boards.

I draw the two boards like this in my void setup()

```
   //drawing grid
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j <10; j++){
      squares.add(new ObjGame( 20+50*i,75+50*j));
      squares.add(new ObjGame( 580+50*i,75+50*j));
     }
  }
```

here is where I create the matrix for the ships and the hit icons. I do it in their own class in order to try and keep my main kinda clean

```
ObjGame(int xi, int yi){
   ship = random(5)<.5;

   x = xi;
   y = yi;
 }
  void draw(){
    pushMatrix();
        translate(x,y);
        fill(25,200,222);
        stroke(c1,c2,c3);
        rect(0,0,50,50);

        if(!ship && clicked){
         fill(255); //white circle for miss);
         ellipse(25,25,30,30); 
        }
        else if(ship && clicked){
          fill(255,0,0); //red circle for hit
          ellipse(25,25,30,30);
        }
        else{
          fill(25,200,222);
          rect(0,0,50,50);
        }
       popMatrix();
      }

      void attacked(){
        if(mouseX <= 500){
        if(mouseX> x && mouseX< x+ 50 && mouseY > y && mouseY < y+50){
         clicked = true;
         println(x+" "+y);
        }
      }
```

i am also trying to print out their coordinates but I want them to print out 0 - 9 instead of their actual x and y coordinates, is there an easy way to fix that or should I just be switching them?

Comment: you should post this question on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: posible duplicte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165810/creating-boats-in-battleship-game

Comment: When I do a project like this, I usually use a data layer where all the informations (like the ships coordinates) are stocked, and then I draw accordingly to this. The advantage of working like that is that you can concentrate on "working on what matters" and forget about the graphics for a while, or improve on the graphics without impacting the gameplay. It's easy to manipulate a 10x10 grid compared to a whole screen's bunch of pixels. How do you keep track of where the ships are located?

Comment: Btw their grid coordinates are the reverse math from their drawing coordinates. For an example, a square drew at `580+50*i,75+50*j` will have the following coordinates: x coord: `(x - 580) / 50` and y coord: `(y - 75) / 50`. The difficulty here is that you have two boards, so to implement such an equation you must know on which board your cell is being drawn.